# 配列のKVO監視について

Tags: swift

KVO監視を行いのですが、（[【Swift】KVOでプロパティーの変更を監視する - Qiita](http://qiita.com/shimesaba/items/30d2cff73bb39f0cd1c7) を参考にしています）
下記のようなクラスを用意したのですが

```
class TestInfo: NSObject {
    dynamic var test1: [UInt8] = []★
    dynamic var test2:UInt8 = 0
    init() {
        self.test1 = [UInt8](count:100, repeatedValue: 0)
    }
}
```

★個所でエラーが出てしまします。配列のKVO監視はできないのでしょうか。

```
「property cannot be marked dynamic because its type cannot be represented in objective-c」
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UInt8]の配列をObjective-Cで表現できないため、エラーが出ているように思われます。

代わりに、NSNumberを使うようにしてみてはどうでしょう？
以下のコードでコンパイルが通るところまでは確認しました。
（Xcode 7.2.1で確認）

```
class TestInfo: NSObject {
    dynamic var test1: [NSNumber] = []
    dynamic var test2:UInt8 = 0

    override init() {
        self.test1 = [NSNumber](count: 100, repeatedValue: NSNumber(unsignedChar: 0))
    }
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
NSNumberを使うという発想がなかったので、大変勉強になりました。
実行してみたところKVC監視も可能でした。